# Is there a way to determine if digital purchases are available on the current device?

Tags: actions-on-google

When building an action for Google Assistant that uses the [digital purchases API](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/digital/dev-guide-digital), is there a way to determine if the API is available on the current surface/device?

Purchasing is not available when running via the Assistant app on iOS, and any attempt to access it results in the message "Sorry, I can't take payments on this device." Additionally, this error terminates the conversation, which is a particularly horrible user experience.

I'm looking for a way to detect that the current device can't take payments, and avoid sending my users into this flow at all when they're on such a device.

The API to fetch available SKUs for purchase doesn't seem to reflect the fact that the user is running on a device that doesn't support purchasing - it returns the same list of SKUs on all devices.

Additionally, I don't see any obvious way to determine if purchasing is available via the parameters provided in the fulfillment callback – I'm using a Dialogflow webhook, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official [Actions on Google docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/digital/dev-guide-digital), the Digital Purchases API doesn't currently include device-type checks, but the Actions on Google Node.js and Java client libraries provide surface capabilities that allow you do this in your fulfillment webhook logic. You can see the surface capabilities in the [rich responses sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-conversation-components-nodejs) as well as in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#response_branching).

Comment: Which surface capability are you saying represents the ability to process digital transactions? As far as I can tell, an Android and iOS smartphone have the same surface capabilities, but the iOS device can’t do digital transactions while the Android phone can.